# FitVids Video Sizes

Tags: files

Using FitVids module. It messes up the sizes of videos in grid display making one column of videos lager than others.

> ex. http://develgobernabilidad.idl.org.pe/idl-sc-en-medios

Any ideas about how to control the size of the videos so that they are consistent?

Answer (score 0):

The videos are not different sizes - your descriptions are different lengths, which is breaking the flow of your pages.

You need to make sure that the `views-field-title` field is the same height regardless of the length of the text description.

Comment: Thanks. That could be it, though views-field-title has a fixed width and min-height. But the title could also be causing the issue.

Comment: The solution I found was the column width. For some reason 3-col or 4-col grids do not display the columns in uniform widths - leading to different sized videos (because fitvid makes the player size responsive). By controlling the size of the column I was able to ensure that all video player nodes were displayed the same size. (I just couldn't answer my own question yesterday).

Comment: But also good to think about your comments too! Thanks again!